# Overloading operators in perl

Tags: perl, operator-overloading

Assuming I have a blessed references / objects `$a` and `$b`, each internally stored as a hashref and have:

```
$a->{_x}
$b->{_x}
```

is it possible to overload the arithmetic operations so when I will do this:

```
my $c = $a + $b;
```

I will have a blessed reference `$c` with `$c->{_x}` equals to `$a->{_x} + $b->{_x}`??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course. Just use your usual constructor for a new object of your desired class in overloaded sub for `+` and set it's value to that sum (or whatever else you want).

Assuming you have `new` constructor that takes initial value as argument, that'd be something along lines of:

```
sub plus {
   my $self = shift;
   my $right = (shift or 0);
   return MySuperNumberObject->new($self->{_x} + $right);
};

use overload '+' => \&plus;
```

Comment: Note: This way of overload-ing has the side effect that, in sub-classes, overload-ed methods that are overridden in the sub-class will not be called; the parent's method will always be called, regardless of whether the sub-class overrides that method. A better approach would be `use overload '+' => 'plus';`.